# Can a vector space of ordered pairs of complex numbers be over real field $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, vector-fields

There's a question in my college's module -

> Let $V$ be the vector space of ordered pairs of complex numbers over the real field $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $V$ is of dimension 4.

How can vector space of complex numbers be over the field $\mathbb{R}$, shouldn't be over the field $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Think of the complex numbers as a pair of reals.

Comment: In general, if $V$ is a vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and $\Bbb{K}\subset\Bbb{F}$ is a subfield, then you can consider $V$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{K}$: just restrict scalar multiplication from $\Bbb{F}$ to $\Bbb{K}$ (i.e the scalar multiplication map $\Bbb{F}\times V\to V$ can obviously be restricted toa map $\Bbb{K}\times V\to V$).

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the complex numbers $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ as an abelian group under addition, and define the action $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $(x,z) \mapsto xz$ to obtain a vector space over the real numbers. When $\mathbb{C}$ is considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, it has $\{1,i\}$ as a basis and hence dimension 2. It is then easy to show that $\mathbb{C}^2$ has dimension 4 (taking, say, $\{(1,0), (i,0), (0,1), (0,i)\}$ as a basis).